# Tiff file after rotation lose colors

Tags: java, image, tiff, jai

My task is to rotate a tiff image by 90°. I found a few examples of how to do this via JAI. So I wrote piece of code form an example I found:

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(rasterFilePath));
PlanarImage pi = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(im);
BufferedImage bi = pi.getAsBufferedImage();
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(-(im.getWidth() - im.getHeight()) / 2, (im.getWidth() - im.getHeight()) / 2);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), bi.getWidth() / 2, bi.getHeight() / 2);
AffineTransformOp opRotated = new AffineTransformOp(at,AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
im = opRotated.filter(bi, null);
ImageIO.write(im, "TIFF", new FileOutputStream(rasterFilePath));
```

And now, a problem is that I have an image rotated, but I lose colors. I get new rotated Image where colors are in grayscale. I checked the difference between image before and after operation with a gdal tool (gdalinfo), and I get:

Before:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\test.tif
Size is 6000, 7000
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=image description
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1000
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1000
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 7000.0)
Upper Right ( 6000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 6000.0, 7000.0)
Center      ( 3000.0, 3500.0)
Band 1 Block=6000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 0,0,51,255
    2: 0,0,102,255
    3: 0,0,153,255
    4: 0,0,204,255
    5: 0,0,255,255
    6: 0,51,0,255
    7: 0,51,51,255
    8: 0,51,102,255
    .
    .
    .
    254: 0,0,0,255
    255: 0,0,0,255
Band 2 Block=6000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

After:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\test.tif
Size is 7000, 6000
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 6000.0)
Upper Right ( 7000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 7000.0, 6000.0)
Center      ( 3500.0, 3000.0)
Band 1 Block=7000x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=7000x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Does anyone know what am I missing with this code?

Comment: You've somehow managed to switch from `ColorInterp=Palette` to `ColorInterp=Gray`. Not enough code to offer an answer but you also seem to now have two 7000x8 bands, one with undefined colour while the original had just one 6000x1 band.

Comment: But the code is only thing that imapct tiff file, so maybe i didn't set some properties and I get default result ?